# why am I getting Null pointer Exception

Tags: java

I am trying to load data from a config file . The code seems correct but not sure why I am getting a null pointer exception . I ran it in debug mode also but not able to find a solution on how to fix it . Appreciate your help .

```
    public class LoadTestData {
    static String s = "src/configuration.properties";
    public ArrayList<String> getValue(String str)
    {
    String res;

        Properties p = new Properties();
        try {
            p.load(new FileInputStream(s));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
 res = p.getProperty("str");
        String[] AL = res.split(","); 
        ArrayList<String> AL1 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(AL));
        return AL1;
    }
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        LoadTestData L = new LoadTestData();
        ArrayList<String> city = L.getValue("Address");
        System.out.println(city.size());

    }   
}
```

Here is the test file configuration.properties file

```
url:https://www.credify.tech/phone/nonDMFunnel
FirstName=vinaya,James,Alex,Alan,Grace,Shilpa,Anand,Saurabh
LastName=Anand,JOnes,West,Delapena,Keesara,Krish,Kiran
Address=37831 Lavender Cmn,33450 Fremont Blvd,1887 Bishop Ave
City=Fremont,Dublin,WalnutCreek
Country =USA
```

I want to load all the input data values into a ArrayList like ArrayList of City ,State etc

Comment: Which line you are getting issue?

Comment: Please add stacktrace of your exception. Stacktrace is telling you where and why exception happened. Also as Gaurav pointed out we need to know how it matches to source code posted.

Comment: This is the exception Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.upgrade.SeleniumHelperClass.LoadTestData.getValue(LoadTestData.java:27)
 at com.upgrade.SeleniumHelperClass.LoadTestData.main(LoadTestData.java:34)

Comment: where is your property "str"?

Comment: Remove the double quotes **p.getProperty(str)** and you should be fine

Comment: @user207421, the closing reason "duplicate" is incorrect imo. It's should be "off topic/simple typo".

Comment: suggest you to learn about SpringBoot application...

Answer (score 1):

I think "str" should be just str as that property key needs to be searched. Please try that.